# Best way to build ISO-date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, date-formatting

I need to build a date in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format on an SQL Server.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Edit

I did try this

```
DECLARE @IsoDate varchar(10)
SET @IsoDate = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Would that be a good approach?

Comment: See [SQL Server CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) - the ISO-8601 format is `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 112)` - or pick any other of the supported styles

Comment: 112 will give you yyyymmdd but still +1 on the comment.

Comment: @JonH: the *exact* format the OP wants isn't available ...

Comment: Styles 120 or 126 (ISO-8601), limited to the first 10 characters, seem to work just fine, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `GetDate()` with the column you are using:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS [YYYY-MM-DD]`

And for many other formats / examples consult this: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Did try something like that. I store the value in a variable instead of selecting but that wont really matter I suppose

Comment: Shouldn't matter just replace GetDate() with the @variable name.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111), '/', '-')`